# is there a sane mercurial tree graph visualisation tool

Tags: graph, tree, mercurial, visualization

I've seen the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828909/how-to-keep-mercurial-graph-flat) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455201/is-it-possible-to-manually-change-reorder-the-revision-numbers-provided-topolog) and they don't have any real answer. While those graphs might be "topologically identical", I would really like my trees to show commits in order they *actually happened*.

[image: main repo (are those snakes on a plane?)]   [image: feature branch repo (looks sane)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a tool to my knowledge, but you're wrong that the questions you link to "don't have any real answer". As explained in two answers to the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12455201/699305) you link to, you can get the behavior you want by cloning your repository in such a way that the changesets are recorded in chronological order. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012597/699305) (by myself) shows how to do it automatically. It's a clone, not history editing, so you can use it with shared repositories.

It's not as simple as using a different GUI, but consider that a hypothetical tool with the behavior you want would probably have other shortcomings. Stick to your favorite GUI and adjust the repo instead.

Comment: thank you for that. yes, I've seen that one, and that's a possibility, but this is a question of "keeping it all in my head" vs "helping me understand what's going on", and visualisation is used exactly for that purpose. If I understood everything with perfect clarity , I wouldn't need to reorder anything in the first place. 
I'm not convinced there would be any shortcomings to reordering commits by time, unless time was out of sync between committers.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Fixing commit order will improve visualization, hence understanding. The strange display order is due to some changesets arriving at your repo long after they were committed to their local repo; they are displayed in order of arrival, not commit time. Nobody thought that some hosts were set to the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

SourceTree (Git/Hg Ui tool) has both modes of graph display: **date order** and more rigorous **ancestral order**.

To use date ordering, you must be absoultely sure all committers have their ntp sync on and date/time zone set correctly.
Сhronological display breaks when trying to show commits from hosts with unsynchronised or invalid date/time, displaying those on their own line out of nowhere.