# Howto let tortoisehg order revs by time?

Tags: tortoisehg

Problem: I committed rev A, then pulled, pulled revs(B) displayed on top of A, even if B was committed early than my rev A, like below:

```
614 fix #43                Jack  2 hours age 
613 Complete feature XX    Tom   1 min ago
```

refresh the repo or restart tortoisehg does change the order. I have to clone a new copy, then use new copy's .hg folder overwrite my current .hg folder.

Is there convenient way to do this?(I am using latest version:3.9)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455201/is-it-possible-to-manually-change-reorder-the-revision-numbers-provided-topolog. The question is about hg rather than thg, but the answers touch on thg as well

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson thank you!